# Adjacent Pair function in prolog

Tags: prolog

what should I do to the following to get the result like this:

```
adjpair(L): The list L consists of pairs of adjacent identical values.
?- adjpair([a, a, b, b, c, c]).
true
?- adjpair([a, b, a, b]).
false
?- adjpair([a, a, a, X]).
X = a
```

The one I have so far is:

```
pair([H|T]) :-
    select(H, T, T1),
    \+ is_in(H, T1),
    pair(T1).
pair([X,X]).

is_in(X, [H|_]) :-    
    X == H.   
is_in(X, [_|T]) :-
    is_in(X, T).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adjpair([X, X]).
adjpair([X, X | Rest]) :-
    adjpair(Rest).
```

(will return false for an empty list, which is probably the desired behavior, but it's not completely clear from the question).